# Can I ban external executable content (external javascript)?

Tags: javascript, security, cryptography

I am working on a javascript program that does client side decryption. The code is retrieved from a trusted source, but it uses a gui toolkit (semantic ui). I have packaged semantic ui, however, it semantic still loads some external content from google (fonts). I want to make sure that no third party would be able to inject code and interfere with the client side decryption (steal passwords). Is it possble for be to ban all executable content that doesn't come from the source domain?

Comment: When you say "a javascript program", do you mean a web application? A `node.js` app? Some other framework?

Comment: A web appplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible to restrict executable content (or any content) to that which originates from your domain. You would want to use a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP), and you could probably use something like `script-src 'self'; font-src 'fonts.google.com'`. You should also use `https` to make it more difficult for an attacker to tamper with/spoof scripts.

Comment: This seems to be *almost* exactly what I want. It seems that it blocks even harmless content, such as images, but that can be worked around. Thanks!